# How to get the number of exe instances from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I would like to know how many instances of chrome.exe are in memory.  I know I can list them via `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe"`, but how do I simply get the number of instances?

Comment: Is PowerShell an option?   (get-process -name chrome).count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output and use the "find" command, with the /c parameter.

```
find /c "STRING"
```

So in your case, it could be:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" | find /c "chrome"
```

Since you're looking for the "chrome.exe" processes.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find